# Ubuntu Variable to output on webpage

Tags: ubuntu, bash, environment-variables, webpage, snmp

I'm at the edge of my technical knowledge and I need your expertise.
I want to view the output of a certain command on Linux onto a webpage.
I am managing a number of devices which I always monitor the Environment Temp, Power-loading etc and I want it in a single pane.
I want to know if I can use zenity into a webpage to view the variables, or is there a terminal console that can be embedded into webpage so that I can run watch command.

Just to give you an idea how shallow is my knowledge for scripting:

```
#watch -n 2 "snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 10.0.0.2 Temp.C; snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 10.0.0.3 Temp.C"
```

Comments and suggestions are appreciated.

THANKS!

Comment: If you are looking for a simple solution, note that browsers can display plain text files.

Comment: Hi John! Yes I know it is possible to display a plain text file, but would it change if the file is updating every 2 secs? Aside from refreshing the page, how can it automatically updates the display? Thanks.